# How can I get a UIAButton value?

Tags: ios, ios-ui-automation

I have a button that every time you tap it, it changes it's value. I need to perform some UI testing and check for the value before tapping it.

But no matter which option I use, I always get an empty response:

```
UIALogger.logMessage(window.buttons()[0].label);
UIALogger.logMessage(window.buttons()[0].value);
```

BTW, if I use tap(), the button gets tapped, so I have the correct button with that selector.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`label` and `value` are both functions.  Try it like this:

```
UIALogger.logMessage(window.buttons()[0].label());
UIALogger.logMessage(window.buttons()[0].value());
```